# I need to be able to select columns in Excel by specifying column numbers in vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim count As Integer
Dim myData As Workbook
Dim col As Integer, rng As Range, n#, b#

col = Selection.Column 'choose the column to count the values from

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(col)) = 0 Then
  MsgBox "You have selected a blank column"
  n = 0
Else
  Set rng = Intersect(Columns(col), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
  On Error Resume Next
  b = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).count
  n = rng.Cells.count - b - 1
  On Error GoTo 0
  Worksheets("sheet1").Select
```

Instead of `column.selection`, I need to be able to choose the column by specifying the column number or name.

Comment: `Columns(1) = Column one` or `Columns("A")  = Column one` now set your `Dim col As Range` and `col = Columns(1)`

Comment: runtime error- object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: You need to use `set col = Columns(1)` sry was clear, let me know

Comment: error - type mismatch.

Comment: Can you update your post with current code?

Comment: @0m3r sorry, i had not changed "columns(col)" to "col". it is working perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143655/discussion-between-11user2614896-and-0m3r).

Comment: @11user2614896 please accept 0m3r's answer as an answer. It seems unanswered now.

Answer (score 1):

*Simply use `Columns(1) = Column one` or `Columns("A") = Column one`*

***[Worksheet.Columns Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197266.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)***

> *Returns a Range object that represents all the columns on the active worksheet. If the active document isn't a worksheet, the Columns property fails.*

Example

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Font.Bold = True
```

Or

***[WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx)***

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1)), same as column 1
```